# static declaration of ‘DisplayMenu’ follows non-static declaration

Tags: c, static, defined

Why do I keep getting this error? HELP ME this is homeowrk. I'm obiously new to programming help.
$ gcc homework.c
homework.c: In function ‘main’:
homework.c:32:6: error: static declaration of ‘DisplayMenu’ follows non-static declaration
homework.c:11:7: note: previous declaration of ‘DisplayMenu’ was here

```
#include <stdio.h>

void DisplayMenu();
void numberPlus10();
void numberTimes2();
void numberMinus1();
void numberTimesnumber();

int main (void)
{
    int choice;
    void DisplayMenu();
    scanf("%i", &choice);   

    switch (choice)
    {
        case 1:
            numberPlus10();
            break;
        case 2:
            numberTimes2();
            break;
        case 3:
            numberMinus1();
            break;
        case 4:
            numberTimesnumber();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

void DisplayMenu()
{
    printf("1. Number + 10\n");
    printf("2. Number * 2\n");
    printf("3. Number - 1\n");
    printf("4. Number * Number\n");
}

void numberPlus10()
{
    int x;
    printf("Please enter a number:\n");
    scanf("%i", &x);

    printf("Your number + 10 is %i\n", x + 10);
}

void numberTimes2()
{
    int x;
    printf("Please enter a number:\n");
    scanf("%i", &x);

    printf("Your number * 2 is %i\n", x * 2);
}

void numberMinus1()
{
    int x;
    printf("Please enter a number:\n");
    scanf("%i", &x);

    printf("Your number - 1 is %i\n", x - 1);
}

void numberTimesnumber()
{
    int x;
    printf("Please enter a number:\n");
    scanf("%i", &x);

    printf("Your number squared is %i\n", x * x);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C we don't implement functions inside any blocks. Instead functions shall be implemented in global scope.

Remove the very last right bracket and put it right after end of the `switch` in `int main(void)`, and there shall be no more errors.

**EDITED:**

First of all.. I'm sure above is why your source code fails to compile.

Also, please check David's answer, since we all believe that you made a function declaration while you're intending to call it -- although this mistake didn't trigger an compile time error.

Answer (score 0):

Pengyu CHEN is ofcourse right! But! You have another error there.

```
 int choice;
 void DisplayMenu();  // You should not declare a function here.
 scanf("%i", &choice);
```

I guess you intend to call this function - so just remove "void" from the beginning of the line.

```
 int choice;
 DisplayMenu();   // Call DisplayMenu
 scanf("%i", &choice);
```

And ... please read language specs

Comment: No it's not the problem. `You can not declare a function inside another one.` Indeed we can.

Comment: Right. But TS obviously intended to CALL the function instead of declaring it.

Comment: Sorry but I shall point out that actually I haven't checked the language specs, so I don't know exactly how this is dealt in the standard of C. However, in `GCC 4.7.2` it is legal to declare a function inside another one, which does nothing but declares a language. And in compile time it won't generate any errors(but in linkage time it would, if you've tried to call the function and it hasn't been implemented anywhere.)

Comment: Oh yes that's true. I didn't notice that. XD Thank you for pointing it out.